# Setting the request URL of a Suitelet form

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have a form with text fields that I want to send to another server. The problem I am having is that I don't know how I set the request URL. I want to send the contents of the form to another URL and then process the response into Netsuite records. Below is the format of how the code will look. Any ideas on how I'm supposed to set that URL? Should I be using `nlapiRequestURL()`?

```
function mainFunction(request, response){
  if (request.getMethod() == 'POST'){
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Form');
    form.addField('field_one', 'text', 'value 1');
    ...
    ...
    form.addSubmitButton('Submit');
    // on submit send to specified URL
    // response processed
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `form.addSubmitButton`, whenever that is clicked, NetSuite will POST the request back to the same Suitelet that drew the form. This POST request should contain all of the field values from your Suitelet form.

Since you are already rendering your form when the Suitelet receives a POST request, you'll have to decide how to differentiate between the initial POST to render the form, and the POST from the submit button.

If you are sending a request to a different URL (e.g. another Suitelet, or a web service somewhere), then you are correct that you would use `nlapiRequestURL`.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. So I think I'll use `nlapiRequestURL` by sending it through the third `script` parameter in the `addButton()` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you use addSubmitButton, the Suitelet will use the same URL passing the field values to the same url.  If you want to send the data to a different URL you can use addButton and put a custom function that will send the data to that URL.

Comment: The same URL as what exactly? What would be the original URL the contents would be submitted to?  Also, for the addButton function, you mean to put the custom function where the script parameter is here `addButton(name, label, script)`?

Comment: It would the URL Netsuite uses when you are executing/running your suitelet. Yes, you can put the function there or call the function.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to send the request through the `addButton` function.